# Can I make this array one line code that only adds to the array if it finds the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to make this one line code array.
It will need to return only the files that been found inside one of the directories.

```
files = ['text.txt', 'fdsafdsa.txt', 'example.txt']

def search_file(file):
    return [glob.glob(f'**/{i}', recursive=True) for i in file]

found = search_file(files)

#output contains the array also with empty objects
```

the output contains an array that also has the empty objects.

my question is if its possible to create an if statement on the action I do with glob

Comment: Does it return empty lists or strings in the list?

Comment: it returns for example


['', 'fdsafdsa.txt', '']

and I want it to output without the empty ones

Comment: `[f for f in [glob.glob(f'**/{i}', recursive=True) for i in file] if f != '']`

Comment: thanks! I changed it a little since '' didn't seem to work I checked the length of it.

```
return [f for f in [glob.glob(f'D://**/{i}', recursive=True) for i in file] if len(f) > 0]
````

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This monstrosity removes empty lists and flattens in one line

```
def search_file(file):
    return [item for sublist in [glob.glob(f'**/{i}', recursive=True) for i in file] if sublist != [] for item in sublist]
```

Here is a more readable version

```
def search_file(file):
    matches = [glob.glob(f'**/{i}', recursive=True) for i in file]
    # remove [] and flatten
    return [item for sublist in matches if matches != [] for item in sublist]
```

Comment: haha is it pythonic to do this or am I better of writing it longer?

Comment: @baslandman You should really split this into at least two lines to make it more readable but in the question it sounded like you wanted it in one line